# Can't seem to load c3 chart library angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I'm trying to use these c3 angular charts, but nothing seems to be showing up on the page. THere are no console errors I can find and I've followed the tutorial but nothing appears still.

I've pulled the git repo and referencing the files I think I need.

Why can't I see anything?

Charts:

https://github.com/jettro/c3-angular-directive

Tutorial:
http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="chart_test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

  <head>


  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ChartController">
    <h1>Line Graph</h1>
      <div id="chart1"></div>
      <c3chart bindto-id="chart1" show-labels="true">
        <chart-column column-id="line1"
                      column-name="Line 1"
                      column-color="green"
                      column-values="30,200,100,400,150,250"
                      column-type="line"/>
        <chart-points point-radius="5"
                      show-point="true"
                      point-expand-enabled="true"
                      point-expand-radius="10"/>
    </c3chart>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="c3-angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="ChartController.js"></script>




  </body>

</html>
```

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module("chart_test", []);
```

Chart Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("chart_test");

myApp.controller("ChartController", ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.message = "hi";






}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on the subject, but in the [getting started section of the page you provided](http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/#getstarted), it says

> You have to add the following libraries and stylesheet.

And then lists the following code:

```
<link href="css/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="js/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/c3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/c3-angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

From what I see, you have included `d3.min.js`, `angular.min.js`, `c3-angular.min.js`, `app.js` but NOT `c3.min.css` and `c3.min.js`.
I would advise you to try including them and if it then still doesn't work, update your question with how that went.